# Time calculation from beginning to till page up completly using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate web page using python selenium, but my task is to calculate complete page up timing (for example when we open the web page using .get('url') from that time to load all the parameters on page. example2-if click any button and will open new tab here also need to calculate time). Please could someone help me how to calculate timing.

Comment: I believe you are looking something like that.
follow link--> https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/how-to-measure-client-side-page-load-time

Answer (score 0):

The advantage you have is that selenium step for going to a url = the time the page takes to load. Once the page is done loading, that step will be seen as completed.

So a simple way would be to start a timer, then go to the url and then stop the timer.

Try something like:

```
import time

stopwatch = Stopwatch()
stopwatch.start()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
stopwatch.stop()
```

Then you can get the value and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. how are you importing Stopwatch() module in the second line. because when i execute the code (python 2.7 and 3.5) i got an error.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know python. Though if you find out how to get stopwatch functionality working, this is your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
# Do some action
end_time = time.time()
print end_time - start_time
```

Comment: you are missing parentheses print(end_time - start_time)